# How can I upload my source code to github when deploying a React app on github pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I recently successfully deployed a react app to github pages. However, is there a way to show both the source code and the built code on github? When I check my repo, both the master branch and the gh-pages branch show the built code, as you can see here:
https://github.com/daanishraj/tic-tac-toe-app/tree/master

However, I want a visitor to be able to see the .js files where I have defined my components etc.

How can this be achieved?

FYI:
My app can be found here: https://daanishraj.github.io/tic-tac-toe-app/

Answer (score 0):

just create a gh-pages branch in your repository for deploying.

look mine:
source code:https://github.com/goldEli/miao-ui.
github page: https://goldeli.github.io/miao-ui/